# What are these symbols that crash URLDecoder with UTF-8?

Tags: java, scala, url, unicode, decoding

I'm using URLDecoder to decode a string:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
URLDecoder.decode("%u6EDA%u52A8%u8F74%u627F", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Which leads to the crash

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u6"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194)
    at Playground$.delayedEndpoint$Playground$1(Playground.scala:45)
    at Playground$delayedInit$body.apply(Playground.scala:10)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Playground$.main(Playground.scala:10)
    at Playground.main(Playground.scala)
```

It seems like `%u6` and `%u8` are not allowed in the string. I've tried to read up on what these symbols are, but I've been unsuccessful. I found the string in a dataset in a field called "page title field". So I'm suspecting they are encoded symbols, I just don't know which encoding. Does anyone know what these symbols are and which encoding I should use to successfully decode them?

Comment: Looks like a failed attempt to encode "滚动轴承", which is Chinese for "ball bearings". Why do you think that it is URL-encoded at all?

Comment: Ah, look here: [Non-standard implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations).

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [non-standard UTF-16-based encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) of "滚动轴承", which is Chinese for "ball bearings".

I'd suggest to just `.replaceAll` `%u` by backslashes, and then use `StringEscapeUtils` from Apache Commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
val unescapedJava = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str.replaceAll("%u", "\\u"))
URLDecoder.decode(unescapedJava, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
```

This should handle both kinds of escaping:

- The normal escape sequences with `%` followed by digits are unaffected by the replacement and `unescapeJava`
- The weird `%u` are treated specially (replaced by `\u`), and eliminated in the first step.

---

**If** (only if) you are absolutely certain that *all* code points got encoded in this way, then you can do without `StringEscapeUtils`:

```
new String(
  "%u6EDA%u52A8%u8F74%u627F"
  .replaceAll("%u", "")
  .grouped(4)
  .map(Integer.parseInt(_, 16).toChar)
  .toArray
)
```

which produces

```
res: String = 滚动轴承
```

but I'd advice against it, because this method will break down for 
inputs like `"%u6EDA%u52A8%u8F74%u627Fcafebabe"` that contain unescaped characters.
Better use a reliable library method that handles all corner cases.

Comment: Yes, there are other strings that are URL-decoded. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Sahand I preserved the step with the URLEncoder after all, I think there might be two cases: standard and non-standard. I kind of merged both solutions now.

Comment: @Sahand Ah, thanks... I know, I've forgotten this `u` three times in a row now, sorry. Thanks. I think it should be correct now?

Answer (score 2):

Your string `"%u6EDA%u52A8%u8F74%u627F"`
is syntactically wrong as a URL-encoded string.
According to the javadoc of [URLDecoder.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and
[Wikipedia:Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) every
`%` must be followed two hexadecimal digits.

May be you meant to use `"\u6EDA\u52A8\u8F74\u627F"`
instead. This would be a syntactically correct Java string (having 4
hexadecimal escaped Unicode characters) and is equivalent to `"滚动轴承"`.
But it still doesn't make sense to URL-decode this string.
Therefore I guess the error already occurred on the *encoding* side,
which produced this malformed URL-encoded string in the first place.